# Use result from one class in another?

Tags: java

I Have 2 classes in Java, and I am trying to use the result from one class as the value for a second class, this is what I have.

DBCall.java -

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class DBCall {

public void generateid(){

    int count;


    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IP:PORT;DatabaseName=SubscriberManager;integratedSecurity=true;");
        System.out.println("Connection Successfull");
        System.out.println(conn); 

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query1= "SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.vSubscriberReporting where [SubscriberEmailAddressStatusID] in (5,1,6,7) and [SubscriberStatusID] = 1 AND [SubscriberAddresseeStatusID] = 1 and CompanySizeCodeID IN (4)";
        ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query1);

        if(rs.next()) //Expecting one row.
        {
    count = rs.getInt(1);
             System.out.println("Value: " + count);

        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DBCall gen = new DBCall();
    gen.generateid();

}}
```

QuickJavaTest.java

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class QucikJavaTest {
 private WebDriver driver;
 private String baseUrl;
 private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
 private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseUrl = "https://testurl";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void ConfirmValue7() throws Exception {
driver.get(baseUrl + "/web/SubscriberManagement/Admin");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SelectedFilter"))).selectByVisibleText("Job Title");
driver.findElement(By.id("Filters_0__Values_GB")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("Filters_0__Values_AF")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button")).click();
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
    if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
    try { if (isElementPresent(By.id("Filters_1__Value"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Delete')])[2]")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SelectedFilter"))).selectByVisibleText("Job Function");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button")).click();
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
    if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
    try { if (isElementPresent(By.id("Filters_1__Values"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

driver.findElement(By.id("Filters_1__Values_28")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.floatRight")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("sqlDetailsHeading")).click();
try {
  assertEquals("7", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.count")).getText());
} catch (Error e) {
  verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
 }

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
driver.quit();
String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
  fail(verificationErrorString);
}
 }

 private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
try {
  driver.findElement(by);
  return true;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  return false;
}
 }

public boolean isAcceptNextAlert() {
return acceptNextAlert;
}

public void setAcceptNextAlert(boolean acceptNextAlert) {
this.acceptNextAlert = acceptNextAlert;
}
}
```

what I want to do is take the value of "count" from DBCall.java and use it as the value to verify at assertEquals("7") in QuickJavaTest.java, Im sure its simple, I just cant work out the best way to do it.

Comment: Why not return the `int` value from `generateid()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **return** the value obtained in `generateid` method from database, then you can use it in other methods as you want/need.

Change the method from returning `void` to return `int`:

```
public int generateid() {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IP:PORT;DatabaseName=SubscriberManager;integratedSecurity=true;");
        System.out.println("Connection Successfull");
        System.out.println(conn); 

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query1= "SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.vSubscriberReporting where [SubscriberEmailAddressStatusID] in (5,1,6,7) and [SubscriberStatusID] = 1 AND [SubscriberAddresseeStatusID] = 1 and CompanySizeCodeID IN (4)";
        ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query1);

        if(rs.next()) //Expecting one row.
        {
            count = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("Value: " + count);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then, retrieve the data in the desired method:

```
@Test
public void ConfirmValue7() throws Exception {
    DBCall dbCall = new DBCall();
    int count = dbCall.generateid();
    //use count as you want/need
    //rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: I have made your changes, and now the console displays -
    Error: Main method not found in class com.example.tests.DBCall, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
    or a JavaFX application class must extend     javafx.application.Application

Comment: @user3768497 do you at least understand what you have to do? Do you know basic Java at least?

Comment: @user3768497 from your comment, seems that you deleted or changed the `main` method inside `DBCall` class, which is not covered in my answer at all.

Comment: Ok, I saw what the issue was there and fixed it, I am quite new to Java and Selenium, if you have an idea of resources for me to read, I would be quite happy to, thank you for all your help by the way :)

Comment: @user3768497 start learning one at a time. I recommend you learning Java first, and the best place is following [the official Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: I have managed to get what I needed working perfectly, thanks so much for your help :)